# jQuery Chosen Plugin - How do I capture focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [this plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) called "Chosen" to turn my plain old select elements into a find as you type deal.

The problem is my existing page has code that fires when the select element comes into focus, and it seems to no longer fire.

[Here's a place you can play around with some sample chosen code](http://jsfiddle.net/queZ6/107/) if you have any ideas you might want to test.  (It's pretty similar to my own code so you can also see how it's implemented.)

Answer (score 0):

that plugin does not seem to have callbacks, that is how i'd do that, instead of .focus() you pass what you need to do on a plugin callback that emulates that event, there is no event "focus" for the markup that the plugin generates.

Comment: mmm forking the plugin and adding the callbacks? or maybe find another plugin that does that for you. or even better, write your own jquery plugin :)